# Can't install 12.10 on a separate partition in a PC with Windows 7

Tags: system-installation

I want to install ubuntu 12.10 along side with windows7, I have already installed win7,My Hard disk(600GB) contains 6 partitions. I want install install ubuntu to a separate partition,but when I try to install ubuntu. it shows only 2 partitions, C(100GB) driver and another partition which already taken the rest of the space(500GB).I want to install ubuntu to a free partition (100GB).

I can create new partition from 500GB, but I am afraid to do that, because my other partitions contains data, could any one help me to figure out this?

[image: ubuntu partition menu]

[image: windos disk manager]

This images took from my lap top(50GB for windows), same issue is existing in my desktop
Thank you

Comment: In windows run `diskmgmt.msc` and take a screenhot. can you upload that image and link it here? which version are you using `11.10` or `12.10` (you tagged the question with 12.10 but title says 11.10)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I'm using 12.10, I have corrected that,ok I w'll upload a screenshot

Comment: From screenshot, your disk seems to be a dynamic disk. You can check this question: http://superuser.com/q/335872/134448 (Note: I don't have much experience in installing ubuntu on dynamic disk).

Answer (score 0):

one work around:

Take the backup of you data available in 500 GB partition on some external drive. Create a new partition in windows in 500GB drive using windows partition manager. Make a 100GB new partition for ubuntu and install ubuntu on that. copy back your data to the remaining 400GB partition.

Comment: Still I did not take the back up. But I created a new partition(deleted the existing one and created),After that I start install ubuntu but that partition was not showing in ubuntu, it shows 100GB for windows and rest of the 500GB as another partition

Comment: can you provide the partition table screenshot from your windows.

Comment: Hi, I added images, I tool these using my lap top same issue is existing in my Desktop, can you tell me what is the wrong with this?

Comment: is there any data in drives:- E,G and F??

It looks like in linux, its adding all of them and showing you. One workaround is to select the partition from windows in which you want to install linux and format it with FAT32. then boot in linux, it will show up as a different drive

Comment: yes, on windows I have, but in linux couldn't see those partitions. I can not format using FAT32 on windows,

Answer (score 0):

It is better to backup your data on an external hard drive then run Windows 7 again. During this new installation of Windows 7, you can create a new partition on which you will later install Ubuntu. I have had some trouble with my system when I did the partition using the Windows disk manager.

Comment: Ubuntu prefers to use at least 2 partitions--a root partition and a swap partition. Furthermore, while you can create partitions in the Windows Disk Management utility that can then be used by Ubuntu, Disk Management cannot format them with any of the filesystems used for Ubuntu system partitions (such as ext4 and linux-swap). Therefore, it's typically best to just leave some unpartitioned space, which you can instruct Ubuntu's installer to use (or, if you wish, where you can use Ubuntu's installer or GParted to manually create the partitions for Ubuntu to use).